# What is "Top X.XX % overall"?

Tags: support

What is "Top X.XX% overall" or "Top X.XX% of the quarter"? I checked my user page when logged out and it shows none. What is it and from when does it come on the user page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the position of the user in the Stack Exchange leagues.

Once you have more than 200 reputation the ‘top %’ badge will appear on your profile.

This week's league is available at https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/apple

> - users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues